# How to make visible files from appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core 6 in Program.cs?

Tags: html, asp.net, json

Appsettings.json has the following code
{
"Project":
{
"ConnectionString": "Data Source=(local)\SQLSERVER; Database=MyCompany; Persist Security           Info=false; User ID='sa'; Password='sa'; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Trusted_Connection=False;",
"CompanyName": "My company",
"CompanyPhone": "+1 (111) 111-11-11",
"CompanyPhoneShort": "+11111111111",
"CompanyEmail": "contact@mycompany.com"
}
}

```
In config.json

namespace MyCompany.Servise
{
  public class Config
  {
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public static string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public static string CompanyPhone { get; set; }
    public static string CompanyPhoneShort { get; set; }
    public static string CompanyEmail { get; set; }
  }
}

I don't know what to do in Program.cs to use <title>@Config.CompanyEmail</title>
In VisualStudio 2019 it was like this and everything worked
namespace MyCompany

{
  public class Startup
  {
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    Configuration.Bind("Project", new Config());

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{
  builder.Services.AddControllers();
  builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
  var dbConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Project:ConnectionString").Value;
  //builder.Services.Configure<Config>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(Config.Project));
  //builder.Services.AddDbContext<FestifyContext>();
  //builder.Services.Configure<Config>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Project"));
  //var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix your class, remove "static"

```
public class Config
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyPhone { get; set; }
    public string CompanyPhoneShort { get; set; }
    public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }
}
```

if it still doesn't work try this code

```
Config companyData = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Project").Get<Config>();
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped to partially solve the problem. It's still not clear to me how to use a declared variable globally in a file with html code. Like this <title>@companyData.CompanyEmail</title>
Error (active) CS8801 Cannot use local variable or local function